# Connect to WIFI from C program

Tags: c, linux, glib, networkmanager

I am using these libraries at the moment to list available networks:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <NetworkManager.h>
```

(which works fine by the way)

Now my question is, how do I connect to a specific network from my C program?
I can't seem to find any good documentation or examples for it.

What I did find was this: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/C/glib/add-connection-libnm.c

But it does not suggest a way to actually connect to the added network.
And also, if it matters; this code will be running on a Linux machine without a display so I'm not looking for anything that requires a graphical application.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When you say that you want to "connect to a specific network", what you do mean by that? Do you want to use e.g. a TCP connection through a specific interface? Then you should [`bind`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) to the interface, but if you do then note that any connections to addresses not routable through that interface will fail. And if you mean something else by "connect to a specific network" then you need to elaborate, like telling us what problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, I want the machine to connect to a wifi and use that wifi to be able to access the internet

Comment: `system("nmcli connection up wifi")`? [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/NMClient.html) if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following API

```
void
nm_client_activate_connection (NMClient *client,
                               NMConnection *connection,
                               NMDevice *device,
                               const char *specific_object,
                               NMClientActivateFn callback,
                               gpointer user_data);
```

details of each input parameters are described here

https://developer.gnome.org/libnm-glib/stable/NMClient.html#nm-client-activate-connection